# Aws Cost and Usage Rport

Tags: amazon-web-services

As far as I know, the AWS Cost and Usage Report report may update up to three times each day or every 8 to 12 hours depending on the previous update.

I've been looking for the exact times when the AWS Cost and Usage Report Billing will change.
please let me know if any one idea on this, Thank you.

Comment: What is your problem ? Is there any question ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am new to this field, i doesn't have much idea in aws,   I want to know at what times CUR will update in a day,i know that it will update automatically atleat one's in a day and upto three times in a day depends on previous update if needed.

Comment: I  want to know at what time cost and usage report will update